# How do datatypes work with c++ and data types with c# in the project with c#

Tags: c#, c++, types, module, type-conversion

There is a module written in c++, it uses structures, as well as data types with ++, the question is, if these modules are added to the project with с#, do you get to interact with these modules if you have your own data types? Maybe if the article is about this, or advice.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/250210/Using-Cplusplus-structures-and-methods-in-Csharp#answer2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure and the orders are the same it should pass fine.
note that c++ has some libraries that c# doesn't so if needed you could use [PInvoke](http://pinvoke.net)